# 項目「選択肢」をクリックで編集しblur()後、もとの状態に戻す方法を教えてください。

Tags: javascript, jquery

項目「選択肢」をクリックし、選択肢を編集し（もしくは編集せずに）、blur()したのち、もとの状態(テキストの状態）にしたのですが、`select`のままになってしまいます。
項目「用途」のように、クリック→blur()→元の状態（テキスト）にできたのですが、
同じように、要素が`select`や`radio`のときはどのようにしたらよいのでしょうか？

ご教授いただけますと大変助かります。

```js
$(function() {
  $('.input_edit').click(function() {
    if(!$(this).hasClass('on')) {
      $(this).addClass('on');
      var txt = $(this).text();
      $(this).html('<input type="text" class="form-control" value="'+txt+'" />');
      $('.input_edit > input').focus().blur(function() {
        var inputVal = $(this).val();
        if(inputVal==='') {
          inputVal = this.defaultValue;
        };
        $(this).parent().removeClass('on').text(inputVal);
      });
    };
  });
});

$(function() {
  $('.input_edit_select').click(function() {
    if(!$(this).hasClass('on')) {
      $(this).addClass('on');
      var txt = $(this).text();
      $(this).html('<select class="form-control"><option selected>A</option><option>B</option><option>C</option></select>');
      $('.input_edit_radio > input').focus().blur(function() {
        var inputVal = $(this).val();
        if(inputVal==='') {
          inputVal = this.defaultValue;
        };
        $(this).parent().removeClass('on').text(inputVal);
      });
    };
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box-body">
   <table class="table">
    <thead>
       <tr>
        <th>用途</th>
        <th>選択肢</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="input_edit">テスト</td>
        <td class="input_edit_select">A</td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
   </table>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

イベントを設定しているところですが

```
.input_edit_radio > input
```

と書いていますがclass名がradioではないですし、タグもinputではなくてselectなので

```
.input_edit_select > select
```

と記述する必要があります。

```js
$(function() {
  $('.input_edit').click(function() {
    if(!$(this).hasClass('on')) {
      $(this).addClass('on');
      var txt = $(this).text();
      $(this).html('<input type="text" class="form-control" value="'+txt+'" />');
      $('.input_edit > input').focus().blur(function() {
        var inputVal = $(this).val();
        if(inputVal==='') {
          inputVal = this.defaultValue;
        };
        $(this).parent().removeClass('on').text(inputVal);
      });
    };
  });
});

$(function() {
  $('.input_edit_select').click(function() {
    if(!$(this).hasClass('on')) {
      $(this).addClass('on');
      var txt = $(this).text();
      $(this).html('<select class="form-control"><option selected>A</option><option>B</option><option>C</option></select>');
      $('.input_edit_select > select').focus().blur(function() {
        var inputVal = $(this).val();
        if(inputVal==='') {
          inputVal = this.defaultValue;
        };
        $(this).parent().removeClass('on').text(inputVal);
      });
    };
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box-body">
   <table class="table">
    <thead>
       <tr>
        <th>用途</th>
        <th>選択肢</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="input_edit">テスト</td>
        <td class="input_edit_select">A</td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
   </table>
 </div>
```

Comment: 早速のご回答ありがとうございます。ご指摘いただいた部分の修正で希望の動作を行うことができました。